# button in table view cell not responding with its index path

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have one table view and two button in each cell named ad edit and cancel. when user click on edit at same time same row cancel button image should change. code is working fine but when i am clicking on first cell edit button cancel button of third cell image is changing insted od first cell. what should i do for this? so that it will change image of same cell cencel button..

Here Is My Code!!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{

simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuNameCell";
cell = (MenuNameCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell== nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuNameCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"---------new cell agin");   
}

 else
{
    NSArray *arrayView = [cell.contentView subviews];
    for (UIView *vTemp in arrayView)
    {
        [vTemp removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSLog(@"---No New Cell hiiii");
    // Setting Tag To UIButton
    _checkButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    _cancelButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];

}
// Creating Label Menu Name
_nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 11, 82, 21)];  
_nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_nameLabel.text =  [_hotel._orderedMenus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Creating Label Menu Cost
_amountMenu   = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(167, 13, 44, 21)];
_amountMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_amountMenu.text  = [[_hotel._menuPrices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

// Creating Text Field For Order Quantity
_textFieldQuantity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,14,42,21)];
_textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
_textFieldQuantity.text = [[_hotel._selectedQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

// Creating Button For Check Order
_checkButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(232, 13, 25, 28)];
[_checkButton setTag:indexPath.row];
_checkButton.titleLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
[_checkButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


// Creating Button For CANCEL Order
_cancelButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(265, 13, 25, 28)];
[_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_cancelButton setTag:indexPath.row];
_cancelButton.titleLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
[_cancelButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(cancelOreder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


// Adding All To Content View
[cell.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubview:_amountMenu];
[cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldQuantity];
[cell.contentView addSubview:_checkButton];
[cell.contentView addSubview:_cancelButton];


//objc_setAssociatedObject(_checkButton, iindex, indexPath,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN );

return cell;
```

}

```
-(void)editQuantity:(id)sender{
button = (UIButton *)sender;
row = button.tag;
col = button.titleLabel.tag;
NSLog(@"Check Button index is %d",row);
NSLog(@"cehck title is %d",col);
_textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 _textFieldQuantity.text = [[_hotel._selectedQuantity objectAtIndex:row] stringValue];

UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_over.png"];
[_checkButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *buttonImageCancel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
[_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_cancelButton.tag =  0;
```

}
     -(void)cancelOreder:(id)sender{

```
button = (UIButton *)sender;
row = button.tag;
NSLog(@"The Row Selected iS At Cancel Order ISSSS----%d", row);
if (_cancelButton.tag ==  0){
    _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    UIImage *buttonImageCancel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_over.png"];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImageCancel1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"];
    [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _cancelButton.tag = 1;
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iHomeDelivery" message:@"Do You Want To Cancel the Order" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

}

Comment: Please add code of editQuantity:

Comment: @rahul - added editQuanty method in code please check it and tell what can i do

Comment: You are changing image of cancel button using instance variable _cancelButton. Are you sure it points to cancel button of same cell? In editQuantity: method you need to get cancel button from same cell by searching for button with tag same as edit button's tag. And then change image of it.

Answer (score 0):

In editQuantity, it looks like you are changing the background images of _checkButton and _cancelButton but you are not specifying the specific instances by way of their tag.

You mention that the cancel button on the third row is changing. Is this the last row that was added to the table?

EDITED
Try something like this in the editQuantity method;

```
UIView *buttonToEdit;
buttonToEdit = [_cancelButton viewWithTag:row];
[buttonToEdit setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have not tested it but in this scenario, buttonToEdit should be pointing to the button in the row you clicked on. As such, you will be setting the background image on the button in the same row.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: @T Davey no its not last cell ...when i click on any cell edit button its changing other cell cell cancel button randomly